# C# calculate date ranges from a list of dates

Tags: c#, date

Given a list of dates (which may not be sorted), I want to build a list of date ranges -

E.g. Assuming MM/DD format,

Input - `5/1, 5/5, 5/6, 5/15, 5/7, 5/8,  5/19,5/20, 5/23`

Output -

```
Date Range 1: 5/1 to 5/1
Date Range 2: 5/5 to 5/8
Date Range 3: 5/15 to 5/15
Date Range 4: 5/19 to 5/20
Date Range 5: 5/23 to 5/23
```

Basically, a range should be continuous.

Comment: Can you post the code you have come up with so far and tell us what is not working?

Comment: Smells like homework.  Mark it as such and add what you have done and what specific problems you are having with your proposed solution.

Comment: How did you ever get those ranges from that input? Looks like the correct answer is going to have a `rand.Next()` somewhere in it...

Answer (score 5):

1. Sort the dates
2. Start a range containing the next date (to start with it will be the first one)
3. Is the second "valid" date the next date which would be in the range? If so, keep going. If not, close the current range and start a new one.
4. Repeat until you've run out of dates, at which point you close the current range and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of `DateTime` (possibly using the same year for them all) and sort it.

It is then fairly easy to find if a day and the next day exist in the list (using [`DateTime.AddDays(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class DateRangerTest
{

    private List<DateRange> GetDateRanges(List<DateTime> dates)
    {
        if (dates == null || !dates.Any()) return null;
        dates = dates.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();

        var dateRangeList = new List<DateRange>();

        DateRange dateRange = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dateRange == null)
            {
                dateRange = new DateRange { Start = dates[i] };
            }
            if (i == dates.Count - 1 || dates[i].Date.AddDays(1) != dates[i + 1].Date)
            {
                dateRange.End = dates[i].Date;
                dateRangeList.Add(dateRange);
                dateRange = null;
            }
        }
        return dateRangeList;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetDateRanges_MultiDateRangeTest()
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime>
        {
            new DateTime(1999,5,1),
            new DateTime(1999,5,5),
            new DateTime(1999,5,6),
            new DateTime(1999,5,15),
            new DateTime(1999,5,7),
            new DateTime(1999,5,8),
            new DateTime(1999,5,19),
            new DateTime(1999,5,20),
            new DateTime(1999,5,23)
        };

        var dateRanges = GetDateRanges(dates);

        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 1), dateRanges[0].Start);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 1), dateRanges[0].End);

        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 5), dateRanges[1].Start);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 8), dateRanges[1].End);

        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 15), dateRanges[2].Start);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 15), dateRanges[2].End);

        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), dateRanges[3].Start);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 20), dateRanges[3].End);

        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 23), dateRanges[4].Start);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1999, 5, 23), dateRanges[4].End);
    }
}
```